# fwrite function's difference in vs2015 and vs2012

Tags: c++

When I call `fwrite()` after `fclose()` has been called, vs2012 didn't throw an error, but in VS 2015 it  throws an error.

[image: The error information capture in vs2015]

The code is below:

```
int main()
{
    FILE* m_pFile;
    char* filePath = "D:\\test_vs2015.txt";
    fopen_s(&m_pFile, filePath, "w+");
    if (m_pFile == NULL)
        return 0;
    char* str = "strNum text";
    int flag = 0;
    while (str[flag++] != '\0');
    int num = fwrite(str, 1, flag - 1, m_pFile);
    int fcloseFlag = fclose(m_pFile);
    if (m_pFile == NULL)
        printf("m_pFile == NULL ");
    else
        printf("m_pFile != NULL ");
    int writeNum = fwrite(str, 1, flag - 1, m_pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure calling `fwrite` after calling `fclose` is undefined behavior.

Comment: *When I call fwrite() after fclose() has been called* -- I don't see a question, just an observation.  If the question is "why", then the answer is that the behavior is undefined.  You do something invalid like this, there is no telling what may happen.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score -2):

file close function does not return in integer, use bool instead.